# L2TP/IPSec VPN on Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I am trying to configure L2TP Using IPSec on ubuntu server 22.04, i have added all the necessary details under Network manager but the VPN does not seem to work and I am not able to ping any network resources.

Also, I am not receiving any error or success notifications, also i don't see that I am getting any IP address from VPN. any help on how to fix this would be great.

Are there any logs I can check?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the question. A VPN does not give you an IP DHCP does.

Comment: Thanks David, yep, sorry for the confusion, I meant probably VPN connection is not getting established and I am not getting an IP address.